# OpenGL render to cubemap using DSA (Direct State Access)

Tags: c, opengl, rendering

I try to render into a cubemap to make a dynamic skybox. And I try to make it with the direct state access feature from OpenGL 4.5.

I get the idea with a simple 2D Texture for off-screen rendering.

Here is how I do it. I paste only the minimal and effective code.

```
// 1. Initialization code
{
    // FBO (Frame Buffer Object)
    GLuint FBO;
    glCreateFramebuffers(1, &FBO);

    // Texture2D for color buffer
    {
        GLuint colorBuffer;
        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &colorBuffer);
        glTextureStorage2D(colorBuffer, 1, GL_RGB8, 1024, 1024);

        glNamedFramebufferTexture(FBO, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, colorBuffer, 0);
    }

    // RBO (Render Buffer Object) for depth buffer.
    {
        GLuint depthBuffer;
        glCreateRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
        glNamedRenderbufferStorage(depthBuffer, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 1024, 1024);

        glNamedFramebufferRenderbuffer(FBO, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    }

    if ( glCheckNamedFramebufferStatus(m_identifier, GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE )
        exit(1);
}





// 2. Drawing code
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

    glClearNamedFramebufferfv(FBO, GL_COLOR, 0, m_clearColor.data());
    glClearNamedFramebufferfv(FBO, GL_DEPTH, 0, &m_clearDepth);

    // Draw stuffs ...

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

So, to render to a cubemap, my idea is to replace "GL_TEXTURE_2D" by a "GL_TEXTURE_CUBEMAP". I know I need to keep using glTextureStorage2D() to create the storage.

Then, I don't know if the RBO will handle a cubemap rendering... I think of reusing it for each face.

And finally, I'm totally lost with the render part. At least, I know I have to render 6 times the scene with different camera angle to complete the cube. But I don't know how to tell OpenGL which face I'm actually rendering.

One of my first clue is to use "glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffer(FBO, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + face)", but it doesn't work.

I saw an other solution when creating the frame buffer with glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer(), but I'm not sure if it's correct.

I dig for solution on the web, but I found a lot of way to do it, some are not compatible with DSA.

Is there someone who achieve this? I just need the main idea.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly this has to do with DSA. It seems to me that you're generally unsure about how to render to cubemaps, regardless of how you create or access those objects. More specifically, it's unclear how you *want* to render to the faces of a cubemap.

Comment: The probleme with DSA is there is some differences when calling function, some are totally different. So I was thinking I'm going the wrong way, maybe.

Comment: "*The probleme with DSA is there is some differences when calling function, some are totally different.*" I do not recall any instance where a DSA function of the form `gl<DSAPrefix><Name>` behaves differently from the non-DSA `gl<NonDSAPrefix><Name>`. There are some instances where there is no DSA equivalent (but these are cases where you really shouldn't be using that function to begin with).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

## Multiple passes with a renderbuffer

You cannot create a cube-map renderbuffer. So if you use renderbuffers for the depth buffer then you have to make six rendering passes, one for each face. To attach each face of the texture to the color buffer in turn you use `glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer`:

```
// 1. Initialization code
    // ...
    {
        GLuint colorBuffer;
        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 1, &colorBuffer);
        glTextureStorage2D(colorBuffer, 1, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, 1024, 1024);
    }

// 2. Drawing code
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

    for(int cube_map_face = 0; cube_map_face < 6; ++cube_map_face)
    {
        glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer(FBO, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, colorBuffer, 0, cube_map_face);
        glClearNamedFramebufferfv(FBO, GL_COLOR, 0, m_clearColor.data());
        glClearNamedFramebufferfv(FBO, GL_DEPTH, 0, &m_clearDepth);

        // Draw cub_map_face
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

## One pass with a geometry shader

Alternatively you can use a depth texture cube map with a geometry shader to dispatch primitives to each of the (relevant) faces.

```
// 1. Initialization code
{
    // FBO (Frame Buffer Object)
    GLuint FBO;
    glCreateFramebuffers(1, &FBO);

    // Texture for color buffer
    {
        GLuint colorBuffer;
        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 1, &colorBuffer);
        glTextureStorage2D(colorBuffer, 1, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, 1024, 1024);
        glNamedFramebufferTexture(FBO, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, colorBuffer, 0);
    }

    // Texture for depth buffer.
    {
        GLuint depthBuffer;
        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 1, &depthBuffer);
        glTextureStorage2D(depthBuffer, 1, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, 1024, 1024);
        glNamedFramebufferTexture(FBO, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depthBuffer, 0);
    }

    if ( glCheckNamedFramebufferStatus(m_identifier, GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE )
        exit(1);
}  

// 2. Drawing code
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

    glClearNamedFramebufferfv(FBO, GL_COLOR, 0, m_clearColor.data());
    glClearNamedFramebufferfv(FBO, GL_DEPTH, 0, &m_clearDepth);

    // Draw stuffs ... (one pass)

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

You'll need to attach a geometry shader that duplicates the primitive for each face. [See here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Layered_rendering).

Comment: In your first example, you re-attach RBO every time you are rendering. Is that correct ? Anyway, I prefer the second way, I will digg more informations with the link you gave me, thank you.

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans: No, I re-attach only the texture layer. The RBO that you use for the depth-buffer is attached only once.

Comment: Yes, I misread the code. BTW I got the job done with glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer() of your first example ! Thx

Comment: For the first example. If I didn't put `glNamedFramebufferTexture`, the FBO will not complete.

Comment: @iaomw: There's already a `glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer`.

Comment: Thanks, I mean in the section of FBO configuration. // 1. Initialization code

Comment: @iaomw: it doesn't have to be complete at that point because you're not yet rendering into it. Once you call `glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer` just prior to rendering it will become complete.

Comment: The second approach using geometry shader is amazing......

Comment: I followed the first option and `glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer` worked perfectly on my AMD card. But on my Intel card, it always triggers a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

Comment: Hi @neo-mashiro; I recommend you open a new question and include your exact code so that somebody could help you with that. I don't have an Intel to test it with anyway, but I heard that Intel drivers tend to be buggy.

Comment: @YakovGalka; Thanks. I do have some clues to test out right now, I will definitely open a new question if I failed. Actually I'm quite happy with AMD and don't even want to bother with minor issues on Intel :D